# Invalid response from ElasticSearch using NEST. I am getting valid responses from curl using CLI however

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am using NEST to make ElasticSearch work with my .net core project. I've just been following the basic tutorial to get started here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html

Unfortunately I have gotten to the point where I am trying to retrieve the data that I just put into the elasticsearch database and I am being told it is invalid when I check the result of the search.

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                        .Index("person")
                        .MatchAll(
```

I checked a few things and I can use the CLI command to return my documents I put in without issue:

```
 {"took":1024,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":    {"total":{"value":2,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":    [{"_index":"people","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":    {"id":1,"firstName":"Martijn","lastName":"Laarman"}},    {"_index":"people","_type":"_doc","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":    {"id":2,"firstName":"Martijn2","lastName":"Laarman2"}}]}}
```

The error message I am getting from NEST:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on POST: /person/_search?typed_keys=true\r\n# Audit trail of this API call:\r\n - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0878608\r\n# Request:\r\n{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}\r\n# Response:\r\n{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index [person]\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"person\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"person\"}],\"type\":\"index_not_found_exception\",\"reason\":\"no such index [person]\",\"resource.type\":\"index_or_alias\",\"resource.id\":\"person\",\"index_uuid\":\"_na_\",\"index\":\"person\"},\"status\":404}\r\n"
```

In terms of the code I am using, I tried to follow the tutorial pretty tightly:

```
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("people")
        .DisableDirectStreaming();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = 2,
            FirstName = "Martijn2",
            LastName = "Laarman2"
        };

        var ndexResponse = client.IndexDocument(person);

        /////////This searchResponse is what is coming back as invalid.
        var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                        .Index("person")
                        .MatchAll(
    )
);

        var people = searchResponse.Documents;
        return people.ToString();
```

Hoping someone can help clarify what's going on... very confused :c

Comment: The error clearly says that "no such index [person]". If you see the response from CLI, the index name is "person" [{"_index":"people","_type":"_doc",..]. Change the index name from Person to People and it should work :)

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. I can barely believe I did such a silly mistake-- thank you so much for catching that! The stress is clearly getting to me haha. For the record this perfectly solved the problem and now I get all my records, thank you thank you!